# Flask-Session with redis sentinel cluster, app dies on new redis master

Tags: python-3.x, redis, gunicorn, flask-session

I have an app written in Python 3.9 with Flask that uses a Redis master/slave setup with Sentinel.

I am trying to handle when a new master is chosen to reload the Session config with it.

I have before and after request functions setup to update the config, but it looks like the session instance running is not taking the update.

Errors in the log are first a timeout connecting to Redis master (because it is dead) and then can't write to read-only Redis node (what is the old master that is now a slave, after recovery).

I have this in a k8s cluster. Trying to avoid the 500 error and just tell Session to use the new master.

Or do I just perform a restart of Gunicorn workers when this happens? How would/should I?

Answer (score 1):

I was also having this problem. I'm guessing you're doing what I was doing, which was initializing a Sentinel object during app startup, discovering the master from that, initializing a Redis client with that master and passing it to flask_session (which doesn't support Sentinel). To fix this, I subclassed RedisSessionInterface as SentinelSessionInterface, passing it a Sentinel instance instead of a Redis. Then instead of sending commands to the Redis client, I use the sentinel client to discover a master or slave (the Redis Python client doesn't have the more modern and less offensive primary/replica terms) and send commands to that:

```
import sys
from flask_session import RedisSessionInterface
from itsdangerous import BadSignature, want_bytes


PY2 = sys.version_info[0] == 2
if not PY2:
    text_type = str
else:
    text_type = unicode


def total_seconds(td):
    return td.days * 60 * 60 * 24 + td.seconds


class SentinelSessionInterface(RedisSessionInterface):
    def __init__(self, sentinel, key_prefix, use_signer=False, permanent=True):
        self.sentinel = sentinel
        self.key_prefix = key_prefix
        self.use_signer = use_signer
        self.permanent = permanent
        self.has_same_site_capability = hasattr(self, "get_cookie_samesite")

    def open_session(self, app, request):
        sid = request.cookies.get(app.config["SESSION_COOKIE_NAME"])
        if not sid:
            sid = self._generate_sid()
            return self.session_class(sid=sid, permanent=self.permanent)
        if self.use_signer:
            signer = self._get_signer(app)
            if signer is None:
                return None
            try:
                sid_as_bytes = signer.unsign(sid)
                sid = sid_as_bytes.decode()
            except BadSignature:
                sid = self._generate_sid()
                return self.session_class(sid=sid, permanent=self.permanent)

        if not PY2 and not isinstance(sid, text_type):
            sid = sid.decode('utf-8', 'strict')
        master_name = app.config.get('SESSION_REDIS_MASTER') or 'mymaster'
        replica = self.sentinel.slave_for(master_name, socket_timeout=0.1)
        val = replica.get(self.key_prefix + sid)
        if val is not None:
            try:
                data = self.serializer.loads(val)
                return self.session_class(data, sid=sid)
            except:
                return self.session_class(sid=sid, permanent=self.permanent)
        return self.session_class(sid=sid, permanent=self.permanent)

    def save_session(self, app, session, response):
        master_name = app.config.get('SESSION_REDIS_MASTER') or 'mymaster'
        primary = self.sentinel.master_for(master_name, socket_timeout=0.1)
        domain = self.get_cookie_domain(app)
        path = self.get_cookie_path(app)
        if not session:
            if session.modified:
                primary.delete(self.key_prefix + session.sid)
                response.delete_cookie(app.config["SESSION_COOKIE_NAME"],
                                       domain=domain, path=path)
            return

        # Modification case.  There are upsides and downsides to
        # emitting a set-cookie header each request.  The behavior
        # is controlled by the :meth:`should_set_cookie` method
        # which performs a quick check to figure out if the cookie
        # should be set or not.  This is controlled by the
        # SESSION_REFRESH_EACH_REQUEST config flag as well as
        # the permanent flag on the session itself.
        # if not self.should_set_cookie(app, session):
        #    return
        conditional_cookie_kwargs = {}
        httponly = self.get_cookie_httponly(app)
        secure = self.get_cookie_secure(app)
        if self.has_same_site_capability:
            conditional_cookie_kwargs[
                "samesite"] = self.get_cookie_samesite(app)
        expires = self.get_expiration_time(app, session)
        val = self.serializer.dumps(dict(session))
        primary.setex(name=self.key_prefix + session.sid, value=val,
                      time=total_seconds(app.permanent_session_lifetime))
        if self.use_signer:
            session_id = self._get_signer(app).sign(want_bytes(session.sid))
        else:
            session_id = session.sid
        response.set_cookie(app.config["SESSION_COOKIE_NAME"], session_id,
                            expires=expires, httponly=httponly,
                            domain=domain, path=path, secure=secure,
                            **conditional_cookie_kwargs)
```

Then during app startup:

```
from redis import Sentinel
from sentinel_session_interface import SentinelSessionInterface


sentinel = Sentinel(
    app.config.get('SESSION_REDIS_URLS'),
    db=app.config.get('SESSION_REDIS_DB') or 0)
sentinel_interface = SentinelSessionInterface(
    sentinel, app.config.get('SESSION_KEY_PREFIX') or 'session:')
app.session_interface = sentinel_interface
```

You don't need to create/init_app a Session instance if you're doing this; all that does is set app.session_interface to whatever interface you're passing. I've tested taking Redis replicas down with this setup, and I'm no longer getting the 500 and read-only errors.

**Edit: After some more aggressive testing, I've found that I do get 500 errors immediately after the Redis pods start updating. After a few seconds, they go away with a refresh. I'm willing to call it good with that, since it wouldn't recover at all before I put this fix in, but keep it in mind.

Comment: I setup a before request to verify the master hasn't changed

@app.before_request
def before_request_func():
    app.logger.debug('before_request_func called')
    _, new_master = session_redis_conn(False)
    app.logger.debug('current master: ' + new_master)
    app.logger.debug('MASTER for session cache: ' + app.config['MASTER_MASTER'])
    if app.config['MASTER_MASTER'] != new_master:
        app.logger.warning('New redis master needed for session')
        # reload app.config values
        os.kill(1, signal.SIGHUP)